# Extend View on single side touch of GridView item Height and Width

Tags: android, gridview, ontouchlistener, zooming, gestures

I need Help to extend layout `ontouchlistener`. Like `Android Studio`, where we can expand logcat(**Android Monitor**) view increase and decrease with point on it. I want same on app, If I expand height of view then below layout should decrease in size and when I touch to above and below view should increase in size, same as right to left and left to right view on run time. **Please give your suggestions**.

What exactly i want is [like this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y7pskqnqc62f43n/VID-20170822-WA0002.mp4?dl=0). Kindly please check this link and let me know if it is possible then how ? Else suggest me that how to do this type of UI in android

Comment: Please check excellent solution for [this](https://github.com/AndroidNinza/android-resize-view/blob/master/how%20to%20work.gif)

Comment: Link is expire, so for answer  please check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not much more knowledge about this kind of view creation and resize that view. But If you want to resize any view in single screen as per that video then you have create custom view extend with [LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html). Please check this project that help you that [how to resize the view?](https://github.com/AndroidNinza/android-resize-view/tree/master)

For drag from one position to another position read [this tutorial](https://www.numetriclabz.com/android-draggable-layout-using-rearrangeablelayout-library-tutorial/). With `LinearLayout` use this [lib](https://github.com/justasm/DragLinearLayout)

If you want to [Supporting Multiple Screens](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) please refer this Google developer documentation.